# Ezplotting an equation of a line and an equation of an ellipse in math lab on the same graph

Tags: matlab

How to ezplot An equation of a line in the xy plane is given by `y = 3x — 2`, and an equation
of an ellipse is given by `16x^2 + 32x + 4y^2 - 24y = 52`.

a) Use the ezplotz command to plot the line and the ellipse in the same plot.

b) Determine the coordinates where the line intersects the ellipse.

Comment: looks more like homework to me. If so, say so.

Answer (score 4):

Did you even try?

```
hold on; ezplot('y = 3*x - 2'); ezplot('16*x^2 + 32*x + 4*y^2 - 24*y = 52')
```

Comment: can you please accept the answer or vote up? glad it helped :)